# Applying Unix's Head on AWK Through Find Command

Tags: linux, unix, awk, find, unix-head

I want to output top 10 lines of AWK command in the list of files given by find,
using this snippet:

```
$ find . -name "*.txt" -print -exec awk '$9 != ""'  \| head -n10 {} \;
```

Note also that I want to print out the file names being processed.

But why I get such error:

```
awk: cmd. line:2: fatal: cannot open file `|' for reading (No such file or directory)
./myfile.txt
```

What's the right way to do it?

I tried without backslash before the pipe. Still it gave an error:

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
head: cannot open `{}' for reading: No such file or directory
head: cannot open `;' for reading: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to do. It seems like you are trying to achieve two things at once.

Comment: @YuvalF: 1. With AWK filter out lines that contain "" in 9th column; 2. Show only top 10 lines - after the filter.

Comment: Try my updated solution.

Comment: One more time with filename printing as separator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to run an Awk program on every file from find that only prints the first 10 lines *each time*.

```
$ find . -name "*.txt" -print -exec awk '$9 != "" && n < 10 {print; n++}' {} \;
```

Answer (score 4):

When running a command with find's -exec, you don't get all the nice shell things like the pipe operator (|). You can regain them by explicitly running a subshell if you like though, eg:

find . -name '*.txt' -exec /bin/sh -c "echo a text file called {} | head -n 15" \;

Answer (score 2):

Based on Ashawley's answer:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -print -exec awk '$9 != "" {print; if(NR > 9) exit; }' {} \;
```

It should perform better, as we exit awk after the 10th record.

Comment: It exits after the tenth record, but not after the tenth printed line which is what the OP wanted and ashawley's answer provides.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way too:

```
find . -name '*txt' -print -exec awk 'BEGIN {nl=1 ;print FILENAME} $9 !="" {if (nl<11) { print $0 ; nl = nl + 1 }}' {}  \;
```

without `head`.

Comment: @Zsolt: I tried. For each file, your snippet keeps going on even after 10th line.

Comment: @Zsolt: thanks. How can I make it to print the file name being (as delimiter)  also?

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` only should work:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -print -exec awk '{if($9!=""&&n<11){print;n++}}' {} \;
```

Comment: @mouviciel: thanks. How can I  make it to print the file name being processed also?